# React Native calendar with multi dots and period marking style

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I want to make calender view with period and multi dots marking style combination with react-native-calender as below image

[Calendar Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bN6TkMHXcy5laltQY2h53zDxMMbXZ--J/view)

so anybody suggests me how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Currently handling multiple ```markingType``` not supported by ```react-native-calendar```. Try to use a custom marking type to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-navtive-calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars).

```js
<Calendar
  // Collection of dates that have to be colored in a special way. Default = {}
  markedDates={{
    '2012-05-20': {textColor: 'green'},
    '2012-05-22': {startingDay: true, color: 'green'},
    '2012-05-23': {selected: true, endingDay: true, color: 'green', textColor: 'gray'},
    '2012-05-04': {disabled: true, startingDay: true, color: 'green', endingDay: true}
  }}
  // Date marking style [simple/period/multi-dot/custom]. Default = 'simple'
  markingType={'period'}
/>
```

For marking

```js
<Calendar
  // Collection of dates that have to be marked. Default = {}
  markedDates={{
    '2012-05-16': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-05-17': {marked: true},
    '2012-05-18': {marked: true, dotColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0},
    '2012-05-19': {disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true}
  }}
/>
```

[image: For markring]

[image: For refereance]

Comment: in my screenshots link I need period + multidots style together